# How to insert conditionally

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert, duplicates

I create a temporary table #tbl(account, last_update). I have following  two inserts from different source (could be tables from different databases) to insert account with last update date. For example

```
create table #tbl ([account] numeric(18, 0), [last_update] datetime)

insert into #tbl(account , last_update)
select table1.account, max(table1.last_update)
from table1 join…
group by table1.account

insert into #tbl(account , last_update)
select table2.account, max(table2.last_update)
from table2 join…
group by table2.account
```

The problem is this could cause duplicate account in the table #tbl. I either have to avoid it during each insert or remove the duplicate after both insert. Also, if there is account with two different last_update, I want the #tbl have the latest last_update. How do I achieve this conditional insert? Which one will have better performance?

Comment: Are there only ever two INSERTs per account? Do you only run this once per account, or could you run again it the next day or a week later? Have you checked out the [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.100).aspx) command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you think you could rewrite your query to something like:

```
create table #tbl ([account] numeric(18, 0), [last_update] datetime)

insert into #tbl(account , last_update)
  select theaccount, MAX(theupdate) from 
  (
    select table1.account AS theaccount, table1.last_update AS theupdate
    from table1 join…
     UNION ALL
    select table2.account AS theaccount, table2.last_update AS theupdate
    from table2 join…
   ) AS tmp GROUP BY theaccount
```

The UNION ALL will build you 1 unique table combining table1 + table2 records. From there, you can act as if was a regular table, which means that you are able to find the max last_update for each record using a "group by"

Comment: @GaolaiPeng it was "GROUP BY theaccount", not "GROUP BY account", can you retry?

Comment: I added select theaccount, MAX(theupdate) from (...) as tmp group by theaccount, then it worked. Thanks for the great idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
 insert into #tbl(account , last_update)
  select  account, last_update
     from
      (
    select a.* from #table1 a where 
     last_update in( select top 1 last_update from #table1 b
      where 
        a.account = b.account
         order by last_update desc)
         UNION 
    select a.* from #table2 a where 
     last_update in( select top 1 last_update from #table2 b
      where 
        a.account = b.account
         order by last_update desc)
      ) AS tmp
```